# C# best way to create instance level interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

As an example, let's say I have a directed acyclic graph with a bunch of nodes. I want to traverse the graph, but each node has a guarding condition. For example, I can only traverse to node `B` if node `A` has a value less than 10. So I have created a method called `IsActive`, which is specific to each node. I tried to model this using an abstract class approach:

```cs
abstract class Node
{
    public int value;
    public abstract bool IsActive();
}

class NodeB : Node
{
    public override bool IsActive()
    {
        // return nodeA.value < 10
    }
}
```

However, I want to avoid creating a new class for each node. So what is the best way to initialise/implement a method at the instance level? I've done some other things, but I am really not sure what the "best" approach is...

Thanks!

Comment: What are your criteria for "the best way"?

Comment: How is the guarding clause defined? Is it depending on the value, or can it be any clause? For example only on Mondays? Maybe you can use a delegate to determine if the node is active and inject just a 'Action<Node>'?

Comment: I guess, what would be considered as best practice. What is the conventional way for defining a class with a method that is initialised/implemented at the instance level?

Comment: It could be any condition, so it might be A > 10 && C <16, or A == 6 || A > C etc etc

Comment: Provide a default implementation for `IsActive` in the base class and make it virtual? Or make `IsActive` a property that can be set? Or what you mean by "avoid creating a new class for each node"? You want an *instance*  of your class for each node, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `Func<bool>` as a property in your `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
 public int Value {get;set;}
 public Func<bool> IsActiveFunction { get; set; }
 public bool IsActive()
 {
   return IsActiveFunction.Invoke();
 }
}
```

That way you can define the condition for every node independently:

```
Node nodeA = new Node();
Node nodeB = new Node();
nodeA.IsActiveFunction = () => nodeB.Value < 10;
nodeB.IsActiveFunction = () => Math.sin(nodeA.Value) == 0; // bad example, because you should not use == to compare doubles, but you get the idea
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need many class. You can simply use your `Node` class but modify it.

```
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; } = 0;
    public int LowerValueLimit { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
    public int UpperValueLimit { get; set; } = int.MaxValue;
    public bool IsActive()
    {
        return Value >= LowerValueLimit  && Value <= UpperValueLimit ;
    }
}
```

Now just create your nodes with their baked in logic

```
// is active will be true for anything between int.MinValue to 10
var nodeA = new Node() { UpperValueLimit = 10 }; 

 // will be active for value between 50 and 60
var nodeB = new Node()  { LowerValueLimit = 50, UpperValueLimit = 60 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go further and create interface that could be implemented to create validation logic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NodeExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var graphRoot = new Node(1);

            var nodeA = new Node(7, new ValidateNodeBehaviour(currentNode => currentNode.Value >= 5));
            var nodeB = new Node(3, new ValidateNodeBehaviour(currentNode => currentNode.Value >= 10 && nodeA.Value <= 10));
            var nodeC = new Node(4);

            graphRoot.Connections.Add(nodeA);
            graphRoot.Connections.Add(nodeB);

            nodeB.Connections.Add(nodeC);

            //traverse the graph
            var currentNode = graphRoot;
            while (true)
            {
                var availableConnection = currentNode.Connections.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsValid());

                if (availableConnection == null)
                    break;

                currentNode = availableConnection;
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IValidatableBehavior
    {
        public bool IsValid(Node currentNode);
    }

    public class ValidateNodeBehaviour : IValidatableBehavior
    {
        private Func<Node, bool> validateFunc;
        public ValidateNodeBehaviour(Func<Node, bool> validateFunc)
        {
            this.validateFunc = validateFunc ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validateFunc));
        }

        public bool IsValid(Node currentNode)
        {
            return validateFunc(currentNode);
        }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        private readonly IValidatableBehavior validatableBehavior;

        public int Value { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Connections { get; } = new List<Node>();


        public Node(int value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public Node(int value, IValidatableBehavior validatableBehavior) : this(value)
        {
            this.validatableBehavior = validatableBehavior;
        }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            if (validatableBehavior == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return validatableBehavior.IsValid(this);
        }
    }
}
```